# windows batch list any file type X in any sub dir named Y (to textfile)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know I can get any file by type in a directory tree with

```
dir /s /b *.ext > list.txt
```

or any subdirectory by name with

```
dir /s/b *directoryName* >list.txt
```

but how do I combine this to get a list of files by type AND sub-directory name?

```
 dir /s /b *directoryname\*.ext
>>The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

read `HELP FOR` and try this in a command line

<strike>for /D %a in (dirname*) do @dir /s /b %a*.ext</strike>

```
for /R /D %a in (dirname*) do @dir /s /b %a\*.ext 1>>list.txt 2>nul
```

Comment: this solution is not recursive

Comment: you are right, edited to include /R to make FOR recursive, now it is.

Answer (score 0):

I may have understood but cant you just do:

`dir /s /b "SubfolderName\*.ext"`

?

Comment: this solution is not recursive

Answer (score 0):

If you want full recursion you can use `findstr` to whittle away what you don't need from a full `dir /b /s`.

```
dir /s /b | findstr /i "directoryname.*\.ext$" >list.txt
```

... will match `.ext` files in any directory containing `directoryname` (including `directoryname01` or `01 - directoryname`), where the directory may be more than one level deep from the current directory.

In the `findstr` search regexp, the `.*` after `directoryname` signifies 0 or more of any character.  In glob syntax it's like `*directoryname*.ext`.  See `help findstr` for more info on `findstr` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /s /b /a-d *.ext|findstr /i /r ".*\\.*dirname.*\\.*"
```

The `/a-d` suppresses directorynames matching the `.ext` mask - filenames only.
The `/r` on the `findstr` is probably superfluous, as regex is default
The `/i` forces case-insentitivity
The string-to-match is

```
[any number of any characters]\[any number of any characters][directoryname][any number of any characters]\[any number of any characters]
```

since `\` escapes `\`